# Redirecting mobile visitors to a subdomain

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, mobile-website

I have an Asp.net MVC website and for that I will making a lighter mobile version and install it on http://m.mysite.com subdomain.

Please tell me what code I can use to redirect the mobile visitors and where should it be placed ?

Also, tell me if this is a better approach or there is an alternative which simply uses CSS to scale down the website ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is a better approach - a responsive build means you only have one code base and one set of content for all devices. Redirecting to a mobile area is the old approach, doesn't always cater for new devices and usually means either duplicate code, duplicate content, or both.

[This](http://www.slideshare.net/yiibu/pragmatic-responsive-design) is probably the best introduction to responsive design I have come across

Comment: Great link mate ! I might not go with it right now, but the issues and concerns highlighted are great points to ponder on. Are you the creator of this slide ??

Comment: Ha ha, I wish! The slide is pretty comprehensive and was recommended reading at a recent CMS conference...

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is check the User-Agent header in the request and redirect as required.  This is available to you through the [`HttpWebRequest.UserAgent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.useragent.aspx) property.  You might also find this [Wikipedia article helpful](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent).

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a good post , you can start with
http://weblogs.asp.net/shijuvarghese/archive/2011/02/25/mobile-enabled-web-apps-with-asp-net-mvc-3-and-jquery-mobile.aspx

Using css to scale down or mobile is not a good option IMO, because you should also consider sending less html/images for a mobile device to save bandwidth.

Comment: Not necessarily, depending on the complexity of your pages, you can reuse your controllers/action and change the views only.